# Can't change VS Code Settings: problem with Json file

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

When ever I try to change a setting in VS Code it shows an error saying "unable to write into user settings".

When I open the JSON file in VS Code it shows there is an error but I cannot seem to find it since I have no idea how JSON works.... Below is all the code in my settings file:

```
{
    "window.zoomLevel": -1,
    "editor.fontSize": 26,
    "editor.tabSize": 1,
    "files.autoSave": "off",
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
}

"highlight-matching-tag.styles": {
    "opening": {
        "left": {
            "custom": {
                "borderWidth": "0 0 0 5px",
                "borderStyle": "Solid",
                "borderColor": "Yellow",
                "borderRadius": "5px",
                "overviewRulerColor": "white"
            }
        },
        "right": {
            "custom": {
                "borderWidth": "0 5px 0 0",
                "borderStyle": "Solid",
                "borderColor": "Yellow",
                "borderRadius": "5px",
                "overviewRulerColor": "white"
            }
        }
    }
}
"prettier.singleQuote": true
```

EDIT: I managed to solve it when I realised that JSON are just stringified JS objects and that VS code only allows single object JSON (not sure if multiple object JSON is even a thing). Basically I neded to move everything into the first {} which is where the official VS code settings are stored (i.e the ones outside were put there by the plugins for some reason).

Answer (score 0):

I also do not know much about JSON. But I know there are online validators like this one: https://jsonlint.com/.

In the line `"editor.formatOnSave": true,` remove the `,`. It could also be the case that VS Code does not like multiple root elements in its JSON - for that you could try to add `{` as the first and `}` as the last character of the file (no guarantee).

Answer (score 0):

The `settings.json` file is **1** dictionary of keys

```
{
    "window.zoomLevel": -1,
    "editor.fontSize": 26,
    "editor.tabSize": 1,
    "files.autoSave": "off",
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,

"highlight-matching-tag.styles": {
    "opening": {
        "left": {
            "custom": {
                "borderWidth": "0 0 0 5px",
                "borderStyle": "Solid",
                "borderColor": "Yellow",
                "borderRadius": "5px",
                "overviewRulerColor": "white"
            }
        },
        "right": {
            "custom": {
                "borderWidth": "0 5px 0 0",
                "borderStyle": "Solid",
                "borderColor": "Yellow",
                "borderRadius": "5px",
                "overviewRulerColor": "white"
            }
        }
    }
},
"prettier.singleQuote": true

}
```

Comment: Yes I figured it out. Thank you you are the best

Comment: @oudwin You can mark the question as solved by marking an answer as the solution